# How to write `performSelectorInBackground: afterDelay:` in one line of code?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, selector, delay

There are methods `performSelectorInBackground:` and `performSelector: afterDelay:` in `NSObject`. How to combine them in one line of code?
Maybe somehow with `NSTimer`?

Comment: your intent is to:
- a) perform a selector on a background thread after a delay, or
- b) to perform a selector on a background thread *and* perform it on the current thread after a delay

Comment: Justin, did you pay attention to question title?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you considered using blocks for that?

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
^(void){
    //your code here
});
```

Also, if it seems like too much writing, there's already a snippet for it, start typing "dispatch_after" and you'll see it.

Answer (score -1):

NSTimer

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
target:self
selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:NO];
```

Comment: This will still execute on the current runloop.